# ROS NetworkSetup

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, community.

I'm following ROS NetworkSetup tutorial and trying to connect Laptop to Desktop.

I succeed to connect Desktop from Laptop by ssh. but after that it asked me password.

I tried Laptop's password, Desktop's password and all other password I know but it doesn't work.

It said : Permission denied (publickey,password)

how do I solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36859/ros-networksetup/) by [gunwoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2656/gunwoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you setup your private and public ssh keys correctly? This looks like a networking problem that is not related to ROS but to your computers network setup generally...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1